# Will it damage rails app to have too many gems installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is it bad practices to add too many gems in the gemfiles?

Especially when there are 2 gems that have similar functionality or testing different gems that has the same function.
will there be conflicts?

Eample: 
[simple form + formtastic] [devise + OmniAuth] installed in one app project.

Comment: How much is `Too many`?

Comment: You can specify which gems are to be used for the production and testing environments

Comment: It depends, but yes, some gems installed together can cause conflicts, like will_paginate and kaminari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many gems may result in a [Boot timeout issue](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout) on Heroku.